# handle duplicate values separately in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file which contains rows like below:

```
113,25CNFW,"test1",1ALNAU,25CNFW
113,25D5L2,"test2",1ALNAU,25D5L2
114,MCF82H,"test3",307531,MCF82H
```

Now, I'm trying to extract 2nd and 4th column of every row by searching certain nos in the 1st column, but whenever the 1st column contains duplicates, my script logic fails as it treats duplicates as single entry. Is there any way to iterate over duplicates in python such that each duplicate value is considered as individual?

```
import csv

mycsv = "/home/test.csv"

def csv_read(fobj, mid):
    reader = csv.reader(fobj)
    for row in reader:
        if mid in row:
            contid = row[1]
            accid = row[3]
            return accid,contid


list = ['113','114']
for mid in list:
    with open(mycsv,"r") as fobj:
        detail = csv_read(fobj,mid)
        print detail[0] + "," + detail[1]
```

Output:

```
1ALNAU,25CNFW
307531,MCF82H

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, in short I want 113 to be considered twice.

I've tried working around with different options, but they didn't work :(

Comment: Hi @optimus-prime.  I tried your code and it worked fine for me after removing the `return` statement (since it's not a function).  Also want to mention that you don't need the `f.close()` as the `with` statement provides code-control and closes the file for you automatically.  You may also want to look at the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library which can be very helpful when working with tabular data.

Comment: Hi @blazetopher. Thanks for looking into my issue and the tips. The reason I'm using 'return'  is because I'm passing values of 'accid' and 'contid' to further part of my code in my script. I've edited the original code now along with the output what I'm getting. I think if this isn't working, I may have to look into pandas library as you suggested.

Comment: I haven't tried the new code, but it looks to me like the issue is that you're starting from the beginning of the file each time you call `csv_read` and then exiting the function after the first "hit".  So you'll only ever get the first occurrence of the desired `mid`.  One suggestion would be to make the `csv_read` function accumulate arrays for `accid` and `contid` and then return those arrays outside of the `for row in reader` loop.  I do believe Pandas would be very helpful as it provides filtering capabilities that would let you extract all of the entries for a given mid in a single call